# Do I need to leave Firefox 57+ behind over lack of OS.File API?

Tags: firefox, file-io, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Per the [draft plan](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/Filesystem) at mozilla.org, it looks like there won't be a replacement for [OS.File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm) that has arbitrary filesystem access.

I have an application based on Firefox that needs to stat/read/write files to non-profile paths. The application is predominantly used off-line, but has advantages if it can also access the web.

**Do I need to move away from Firefox now that they're dropping these 'legacy' APIs?**

I'm not much of a nodejs fan, but it looks like with a *lot* of work I could port my app over to Electron or similar.

---

I have a Bootstrap-style addon that injects privileged functions into the un-privileged Window where the application lives.

The specific use case for OS.File is:

- User interacts with a page that represents their order
- Each item in the order represents a file that either doesn't exist yet or is ready for copying to USB media supplied by the customer
- When user inserts USB media the page is notified that the copy function is available
- The user then clicks 'copy' and the page iterates the 'ready' item.
- Asyncronously, for each item:

  - the path to the item (on a NAS) is determined
  - copying to USB flash is slow, so a streaming copier (similar to "copy a file by chunks" from the [OS.File on-thread examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File_for_the_main_thread)) is used to copy the file to the mounted USB media
  - a per-item progress bar is updated as the file is copied
- when the 'ready' part of the order is copied, the page is notified that it's OK to eject the USB media
- the user clicks a button on the page to effect the media ejection and then the page is notified when it's safe to remove the USB media

The user continues to interact with the page (ordering, searching) while the copying occurs.

---

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking here. You've linked to the very clear document which details the plans for Firefox. If the actual, or planned, capabilities are not sufficient for you, then you need to do something else. Why are you asking us to evaluate this for you? You're the one with all the information. As a stop-gap until you have something else lined up, you can use Firefox 52ESR, which will continue to support legacy extensions into June 2018. Note that you could use WebExtensions' native messaging to transfer data to a native application which could perform the tasks you desire.

Comment: @Makyen I hoped I was missing something obvious that would bridge the gap in functionality. Never hurts to ask. Obviously, if the platform doesn't want to support my kind of app, I'll go elsewere.

Comment: Mozilla has, unfortunately, chosen that they will not support anywhere close to what they once did wrt. add-on capabilities. This has a wide-ranging effects on many of us. Combined with their choice to no long use human review of all add-ons prior to listing on AMO, it makes their browser a significantly poorer choice than it was not that long ago. Personally, it means that I will explore other options.

Comment: Is there a good reason to write it as a Firefox addon instead of a standalone application?

Comment: @Smile4ever It's already written 4 years ago. There's lots of code that I'd have to rewrite, and I'd rather not. If I knew that Mozilla would abandon extension authors in this way 4 years ago, I'd have used other technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the in-browser integration is sufficiently valuable that you want to find a solution that works after legacy extensions are gone this sounds like something you could do with the webextensions native messaging API [1].  As others have said, arbitrary file system access from webextensions (and things like detecting when a removable storage device is attached) is not going to happen.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging